# Changing class with VueJS for several cards

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this page with several cards and each card has its own status radio buttons: ok, missing, error.

I wanna change the status of each card without changing others. So I created a method to change the class on @change event, but as all cards bind the same 'data', like 'status', changing one, changing all.

Let´s see some code

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosCadastrais" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" @change="ok">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosCadastrais" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" @change="falta">
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosCadastrais" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" @change="erro">
```

The script part:

```
var vue = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            status: ''
        }
```

And the method() part:

```
ok() {
    this.status = 'bg-primary text-white'},
    //will code some AJAX too
falta() {
    this.status = 'bg-warning text-black'},
    //will code some AJAX too
erro() {
    this.status = 'bg-danger text-white'
    //will code some AJAX too
    }
```

The hole card deck code is:

```
<div class="card-columns">
            <div class="card" :class="status">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Dados Cadastrais</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                    LOGRADOURO: @{{ rua }}, </p><p> NÚMERO: @{{ numero }}, </p><p> BAIRRO: @{{ bairro }}, </p><p> TEMPO DE RESIDÊNCIA: @{{ tempoResidencia
                    }}, </p><p> CIDADE: @{{ cidade }}, </p><p> UF: @{{ uf }}, </p><p> TELEFONE: @{{ telefone }}, </p><p> CELULAR: @{{ celular }}, </p><p> CEP:
                    @{{ CEP }}
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosCadastrais" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" @change="ok">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">OK</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosCadastrais" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" @change="falta">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Falta</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosCadastrais" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" @change="erro">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Erro</label> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" :class="status">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Dados do Bem</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                    CONTRATO: @{{ contrato }}, </p><p> GRUPO: @{{ grupo }}, </p><p> COTA: @{{ cota }}, </p><p> VALOR: @{{ valor }}, </p><p> PESSOA: @{{ pessoa }}, </p><p> BEM CONTRATADO: @{{ segmento }}, </p><p> BEM ESCOLHIDO: @{{ novoSegmento }}, </p><p> idERP: @{{ idERP }}, </p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosBem" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" @change="ok">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">OK</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosBem" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" @change="falta">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Falta</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosBem" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" @change="erro">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Erro</label> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" :class="status">
                <div v-if="contas != ''">
                    <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Dados Bancários</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                BANCO: @{{ contas.banco }}, </p>
                            <p> AGÊNCIA: @{{ contas.agencia }}, </p>
                            <p> CONTA CORRENTE: @{{ contas.conta }}, </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosBancarios" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" @change="ok">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">OK</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosBancarios" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Falta</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosBancarios" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Erro</label> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div v-else>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Dados Bancários</h5>
                        <form v-on:submit.prevent="sub" action="#" method="post">
                        @method('POST')
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="banco">Banco</label>
                            <input type="text" v-model="banco" class="form-control" id="banco">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="agencia">Agência</label>
                            <input type="text" v-model="agencia" class="form-control" id="agencia">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="conta">Conta Corrente</label>
                            <input type="text" v-model="conta" class="form-control" id="conta">
                        </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosBancarios" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" @change="ok">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">OK</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosBancarios" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Falta</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosBancarios" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Erro</label> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Dados de Patrimônio</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        AÇÕES: @{{ patrimonios.valorAcoes }}, </p>
                        <p> AUTOMÓVEIS: @{{ patrimonios.valorAutomovies }}, </p>
                        <p> IMÓVEIS: @{{ patrimonios.valorImovel }}, </p>
                        <p> INVESTIMENTOS: @{{ patrimonios.valorInvestimentos }}, </p>
                        <p> TOTAL: @{{ patrimonios.valorTotal }}, </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosPatrimonio" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">OK</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosPatrimonio" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Falta</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosPatrimonio" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Erro</label> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Endereços de Patrimônios</h5>
                        <div v-for="imovel in imoveis">
                            <p class="card-text">RUA: @{{ imovel.rua }}, </p>
                            <p> NÚMERO: @{{ imovel.nroReferencia }}, </p>
                            <p> COMPLEMENTO: @{{ imovel.complementoPatrimonio }}, </p>
                            <p> BAIRRO: @{{ imovel.bairroPatrimonio }}, </p>
                            <p> CEP: @{{ imovel.cep }}, </p>
                            <p> CIDADE: @{{ imovel.cidadePatrimonio }}, </p>
                            <p> UF: @{{ imovel.UFPatrimonio }}, </p>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="endPatrimonio" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">OK</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="endPatrimonio" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Falta</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="endPatrimonio" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Erro</label> </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" v-if="correspondencia != ''">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Endereço de Correspondência</h5>
                    <div v-if="correspondencia != ''">
                        <p class="card-text">RUA: @{{ correspondencia.rua }}, </p>
                        <p> NÚMERO: @{{ correspondencia.numero }}, </p>
                        <p> BAIRRO: @{{ correspondencia.bairro }}, </p>
                        <p> CEP: @{{ correspondencia.cep }}, </p>
                        <p> CIDADE: @{{ correspondencia.cidade }}, </p>
                        <p> UF: @{{ correspondencia.UF }}, </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="endCorrespondencia" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">OK</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="endCorrespondencia" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Falta</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="endCorrespondencia" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Erro</label> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Dados Profissionais</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">PROFISSÃO: @{{ profissao.profissao }}, </p>
                    <p> CARGO: @{{ profissao.cargo }}, </p>
                    <p> SALÁRIO: @{{ profissao.salario }}, </p>
                    <p> EMPRESA: @{{ profissao.empresa }}, </p>
                    <p> EMAIL: @{{ profissao.emailEmpresa }}, </p>
                    <p> CNPJ: @{{ profissao.cnpj }}, </p>
                    <p> RUA: @{{ profissao.logradouro }}, </p>
                    <p> CEP: @{{ profissao.cep }}, </p>
                    <p> Cidade: @{{ profissao.cidade }}, </p>
                    <p> UF: @{{ profissao.UF }}, </p>
                    <p> BAIRRO: @{{ profissao.bairro }}, </p>
                    <p> TELEFONE: @{{ profissao.ddd }} - @{{ profissao.telefoneComercial }} </p>
                    <p> RAMAL: @{{ profissao.ramal }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosProfissionais" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">OK</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosProfissionais" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Falta</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="dadosProfissionais" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Erro</label> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Referências Pessoais</h5>
                    <div v-for="referencia in referencias">
                        <p class="card-text">NOME: @{{ referencia.nome }}, </p>
                        <p> ENDEREÇO: @{{ referencia.endereco }}, @{{ referencia.numero }}</p>
                        <p> CIDADE: @{{ referencia.cidade }}, </p>
                        <p> UF: @{{ referencia.UF }}, </p>
                        <p> CEP: @{{ referencia.cep }}, </p>
                        <p> COMPLEMENTO: @{{ referencia.complemento }}, </p>
                        <p> TELEFONE: (@{{ referencia.ddd }}) @{{ referencia.telefone }}, </p>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="refPessoais" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">OK</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="refPessoais" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Falta</label> </div> <div class="form-check form-check-inline">   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="refPessoais" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3">   <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">Erro</label> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How can I do it be as much as DRY as possible, and change only the card I wanna change?

Comment: Can you share whole card code?

Comment: Shared all card block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vue-refs to get a particular element.

Here is simple code to reproduce:

Template

```
<div class="card" ref="card-1">
  <div class="card-body">
    .....
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
   <input @click="setClass(1, 'bg-primary text-white')">
   <input @click="setClass(1, 'bg-warning text-black')">
   <input @click="setClass(1, 'bg-danger text-white')">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" ref="card-2">
  <div class="card-body">
    .....
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer text-muted">
   <input @click="setClass(2, 'bg-primary text-white')">
   <input @click="setClass(2, 'bg-warning text-black')">
   <input @click="setClass(2, 'bg-danger text-white')">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
Methods: {
  setClass(index, className) {
    const elem = this.$refs[`card-${index}`]
    elem.className = className
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Learned one more! Thanks @Manu

Comment: Just need to add 'card at the lines 
```<input @click="setClass(2, 'card bg-primary text-white')"> ``` so it stills been a card!

Comment: Also, it is good approach to save status in the card object as @Rudy suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Add data elements:

```
data: {
  oks: [],
  faltas: [],
  erros: []
}
```

Add some new logic to the methods:

```
falta(index) {
  if (!this.faltas.includes(index)) {
    this.faltas.push(index)
  } 

  // other stuff
}
```

Repeat this for your `erro()` method.

Make sure you add the reverse logic for the `ok()` method:

```
if (this.erros.includes(index)) {
  this.erros.splice(this.erros.findIndex(el => el === index), 1)
}
```

Dynamically change the card class based on the existence of the index:

```
<div class="card" :class="{'bg-primary text-white': this.faltas.includes(1)'}">
```

Add any other conditionals there based on inclusion, such as for `oks.includes(id)` and `errors.includes(id)`

And update the methods for the input elements to pass the unique indexer for this card:

```
@change="ok(1)"
@change="falta(1)"
@change="erro(1)"
```

And just change `1` to `2` for the next card and methods within that card and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to store the status on the object directly. For this to work the list used in the `v-for` must be inside the component `data` so it's editable.

With this approach there is no need to track who has what status, indexes, etc. Each object is responsible for its own status. In this example I suppose there will be classes set up with correct styling, `ok`, `falta` and `erro`.

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body" :class="referencia.status">
        <h5 class="card-title">Referências Pessoais</h5>
        <div v-for="referencia in referencias">
            <p class="card-text">
              NOME: @{{ referencia.nome }}
            </p>
            ...
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
      <button class="some-styling-here" @click="referencia.status = 'ok'"> OK </button>
      <button class="some-styling-here" @click="referencia.status = 'falta'"> Falta </button>
      <button class="some-styling-here" @click="referencia.status = 'erro'"> Erro </button>
    </div>
</div>
```